# http.get or http.request callback only shows within shell - node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js

New to node and trying not to do any callback hell.

I have two files
`routes.js`
`fetch.js`

```
//routes.js
var fetchController = require("../lib/mtl_fetcher/fetcher_controller");
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();

router.get('/', function(req, res, next) {
    res.send(fetchController.getAllTransgressor(function(results) { 
        return results.end();
    }))
});

module.exports = router;
```

and

```
 //fetch.js
    var http = require('http');
    var config = require('./config')
    var Iconv = require('iconv').Iconv

    module.exports.getAllTransgressor = function(callback) {

        var req = http.get(config.urlOptions.host, function (response) {
            var bufferChunk = [];
            var str

            if(response.statusCode == 200) {

                response.on('data', function(chunk) {
                    bufferChunk.push(chunk);
                })

                response.on('end', function(callback) {
                    var iconv = Iconv('latin1', 'UTF-8');
                    str = iconv.convert(Buffer.concat(bufferChunk)).toString();
                    console.log(str)
                });
            } else {
                console.log("handle this")
            }
        });

        req.on("error", function(err) {
            callback(err);
        });

        callback(req)
    }
```

So the goal is to fetch and then show what has been fetch to the screen. The ressource is XML base.

Doing all of this in one block (routes.js) works, but when I try to refactor and set up some modularity my `str` just shows in shell stdout.

Using `req.end()` does not send the content back.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Firstly, you need to send inside the callback, where the result is actually available, as you can't return from an asynchronous function

```
router.get('/', function(req, res, next) {
    fetchController.getAllTransgressor(function(error, results) { 
        if ( error ) {
            // handle errors
        } else {
            res.send(results);
        }
    });
});
```

The same goes for the callback function, it has to be called when the data is available, after the request and parsing

```
module.exports.getAllTransgressor = function(callback) {

  var req = http.get(config.urlOptions.host, function(response) {
    var bufferChunk = [];

    if (response.statusCode == 200) {

      response.on('data', function(chunk) {
        bufferChunk.push(chunk);
      });

      response.on('end', function() {
        var iconv = Iconv('latin1', 'UTF-8');
        var str   = iconv.convert(Buffer.concat(bufferChunk)).toString();

        callback(null, str); // here, stuff is available
      });

    } else {
      callback('Did not return 200', err);
    }
  });

  req.on("error", function(err) {
    callback(err, null);
  });

}
```

Comment: I tried something like this. I run into `callback(null, str) is not a function` when trying to pass on the callback to http.get().

Comment: That's because you've redefined `callback` as an argument to `end`, which has no callback. I've removed that argument from the code above.

Comment: still a blank page. I have the same code as you, and results in `routes.js` is showing the result properly with console.log. It's no more related to callback handling.

Comment: So you get `results` in the route, but `send()` is not displaying it? If you try just `send('something')` do you see that?

Comment: Found it, it's XML related, I just converted it and it's fine. Thanks to you for teaching me how to fix this :)